# PHP function not working on post but works if I am on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am using a popular function for time ago and it works excellent until I use javascript to post to a different page.  I was able to narrow it down to the function below. Verified I am passing a good date to the function. '2019-01-05 15:42:53'  This things have my totally stumped on this.

On my page if I remove the post and just hard code the variables I am passing it works as advertised.  The only variables I am passing are user_id for a simple sql query.

As well if I remove the the line "$dateadded = time_elapsed_string($row['dateadded']); " the page loads great with my post request.

```
        echo $dateadded ;   // this passes the data above
        $dateadded = time_elapsed_string($row['dateadded']); 

    function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
        $now = new DateTime;
        $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
        $diff = $now->diff($ago);
        $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
        $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;
        $string = array(
            'y' => 'year',
            'm' => 'month',
            'w' => 'week',
            'd' => 'day',
            'h' => 'hour',
            'i' => 'minute',
            's' => 'second',
        );
        foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
            if ($diff->$k) {
                $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
            } else {
                unset($string[$k]);
            }
        }
        if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
        return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
    }
```

*****NOTE***

I updated my post with something that fixed the issue but I have no freaking idea why it even matters.

I removed

```
  if($_POST['user_id'] != ''){
```

and the following bracket.  Yes it was at the very bottom and highlighting it showed it was closed with the one above.

```
 }
```

I still have this line in there

```
 $user_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['user_id']);
```

script is working now and I have no idea why that did it.

Comment: with `ajax` `post` the php then is a separated file so you'll need to include the function to the file again .. because I think your function not included in your php file .. simple way to check that is to copy/paste the function inside the php file (just for testing)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mohamed.  The function is included in this php file and the proof it that I can remove references of the post and hard code my variables I am passing and run the page by itself with no issues at all.

Comment: These are the simple lines I am remove from the code and hard code.

          if($_POST['user_id'] != ''){ 
 $user_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['user_id']);

Remove the closing bracket 

Put $user_id='33';

Works.  Stumped on why it matter if I am on the page or passing it a post variable.

Comment: on `$.post` callback `function(data){console.log(data)}` and see what is the error you'll get

Comment: I have added echo comments to each line and can see on the Network response where it fails.   This is how I know where it is dying.

Comment: Ok the function you provided works well .. please include the nonworking code .. if thing wrong with the provided code it should be `$row['dateadded']`

Comment: may be `!=` should be `!==` and you need to use `if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && $_POST['user_id'] !== '')`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Converting the variable to a datetime format before passing it in the function:

```
$newDate = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['dateadded']);
$dateadded = time_elapsed_string($newDate);
```

Comment: If I hardcode the variables 
Messages 
to 33
From Lisa 
Subject: something
Message: asdfasdf asdfasdf.....
dateadded 12 hours ago

Proof that the function does in fact work with the same variable I am passing. 

Put my post back in and here are the results.
$test = $row['dateadded'];
  echo "test $test";   ///this worked
     $newDate = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['dateadded']);  
     echo "stuff $newDate";   //died on this line. 

I got an echo from the test and nothing for $newdate.  Died on that line.

Comment: Updated my post with something that worked.  No reason why it should matter.  All backets were closed.   I looked for hidden characters and there were none.